# Is there a parser from Python-Z3 to Z3/smt2?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, quantifiers

I am working with the Python API of Z3, because of convenience, but sometimes I need to convert my Python results into readable input for Z3/smt2. For instance, whenever I perform quantifier eliminations, I need to input the result into the other format.

Often it is easy to do it by hand, but sometimes I get large expressions like:

```
[[Not(y <= x),
  Not(And(x +
          -1*If(y + -1*ext >= 0, y + -1*ext, -1*y + ext) +
          -1*ext <=
          -2,
          Or(If(y + -1*ext >= 0, y + -1*ext, -1*y + ext) >=
             1,
             And(If(y + -1*ext >= 0, y + -1*ext, -1*y + ext) <=
                 0,
                 If(y + -1*ext >= 0, y + -1*ext, -1*y + ext) >=
                 1)))),
  Not(And(x + -1*ext <= -2,
          If(y + -1*ext >= 0, y + -1*ext, -1*y + ext) >= 2))]]
```

... whereas I would need something like `(And(Not...))`.

Is there a parser from Python-PY to Z3? I mean: it takes the large solution above (or any other formula) and returns the Z3/smt2 equivalent. As for an example, I want to execute this:

```
x, y, z = Ints('x y z')

l_1 = (y > x)
l_2 = (z > x)
l_3 = (z >= y)

f_1 = l_1
f_2 = Implies(l_2,l_3)

phi = And([f_1, f_2])


t = Tactic("qe")
phi_s = Goal()
phi_s.add(ForAll([z], phi))
phi_qe = t(phi_s)
print(phi_qe)
```

... which produces `phi_qe = [[Not(y <= x), Not(x + -1*y <= -2)]]`.

Then, use some `parse(phi_qe)` (which is what I ask for) and get this: `(and (> y x) (> (+ x (- y)) -2)))))`

PS: The closest solution I found is [Z3Py: Parsing expressions using eval or z3.parse_smt2_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359663/z3py-parsing-expressions-using-eval-or-z3-parse-smt2-string), where they use a function `parse_smt2_string` for the exact opposite of what I want.

Comment: The reason that you've only found results that do the opposite of what you want is that the term "parsing" means the opposite of what you're using it to mean. Anyway, you want the `sexpr()` method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I thought parsing just meant transforming some data (keeping its semantics) in order to make it a feasible input for another tool. Anyway, I apply `phi_qe.sexpr()` but still get `[[Not(y <= x), Not(x + -1*y <= -2)]]`. I am using the example of the post. Any idea?

Comment: All I can tell you is that there's no way that `sexpr` would return that output, so you must have done something wrong (like editing one file and then running another or assigning the result of `sexpr` to a variable but then printing something other than that variable or reassigning that variable to something else before printing it etc.)

Comment: You are right, I was making an assignment first. Now, I see it creates a form "goals(goal..." what is the meaning of this?

Comment: The result of applying a tactic (and thus `phi_qe`) is a set of goals, which is represented as an `ApplyResult` object in the API and as `(goals ...)` in s-expression syntax. Also see: https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/docs/strategies/goals/

Comment: I think I understand. My only doubt is why Python's API does not also show that and only returns `[[Not(y <= x), Not(x + -1*y <= -2)]]` without "goals" information explicitly expressed.

Comment: `sexpr()` is the way to go as @sepp2k mentioned. However, I think mixing/matching SMTLib/Z3-Python like this sounds like a bad idea. Unless it's for purely presentation reasons, I'd question why you need this back-and-forth.

Comment: The reason is that I need the input in SMTLib format for another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @sepp2k, `sexpr()` is the way to go.

However, I think mixing/matching SMTLib/Z3-Python like this sounds like a bad idea. Unless it's for purely presentation reasons, this'll no doubt create friction between different layers of programming.

Based on your other question I gather these are skolem functions generated by some other mechanism. Perhaps it'd be best to tweak that system to spit out Python? Or, if the generated functions are simple enough, you might want to write a program to do that yourself. That would be a program that can be written any language, that takes these strings and generate simple Python snippets. Skolem functions generated by z3 tend to be simple enough in structure, so this might be a viable alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. As far as I have been testing, using "sexpr()" allows me to (as you noticed) use formulae as inputs for tools that generate Skolem functions. There are some formulae for which the amount of parenthesis makes it complicated to use it directly, but it does work. Thanks a lot. As you also noticed, my problem now is what to do with such generated functions (which is the other question), since they are printed in Z3. I think I will use the "parse_smt2_string" you suggested (try to make it more general), but at the end generating Python code should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

We have got two ways:

1. solver.sexpr()
2. solver.to_smt2()

For example: For the code segment;

```
x = Int('x') 
s.add(x > 10) 
s.add(x < 20)
```

s.sexpr() will return:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (> x 10))
(assert (< x 20))
```

and s.to_smt2() will return:

```
; benchmark generated from python API
(set-info :status unknown)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert
 (> x 10))
(assert
 (< x 20))
(check-sat)
```