# Memory Error while convert string to list in python

Tags: python, string, list, eval

I am using operating system MacOS Sierra(version 10.12.5) and log in as the root user.

The length of the string is 38405.

I am using eval to convert string to list

I have added following in my python file:

1.

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, [0x10000000, resource.RLIM_INFINITY])
sys.setrecursionlimit(0x100000)
```

But get the following error

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, [0x10000000, resource.RLIM_INFINITY])
ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit
```

2. If I use `os.system('ulimit -s 65532')` getting following error

Same Error

```
s_push: parser stack overflow MemoryError
```

How to resolve this issue?

The string, I tried to convert can be found the following link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_JtQtd0sA4nMlJ0RGNRU3JZVGM

Definition of the function present in the string is as follows

```
def expres(functor,args=[]):
    return [functor]+args
```

Comment: Why are you messing around with the resources? 38405 characters is not a long string.

Comment: Nick. When tried to convert string to list, it returning "s_push: parser stack overflow MemoryError" error

Comment: Please paste the string you are trying to convert.

Comment: I have uploaded string in the URL https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_JtQtd0sA4nMlJ0RGNRU3JZVGM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005760/python-nested-lambdas-s-push-parser-stack-overflow-memory-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: nested lambdas -- \`s\_push: parser stack overflow Memory Error\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005760/python-nested-lambdas-s-push-parser-stack-overflow-memory-error)